# Using generalized programming for returning the element of a nearest to val

Tags: java

I need to return the element c nearest to val using generalized programming. I continue getting the following error when I try to compile:

Selector.java:50: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method get(int)
location: interface java.util.Collection
      double distance = tm.distance(c.get(0), val);

Not sure how to correct this. Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public final class Selector {

   private Selector() { }

   public static <T> T nearest(Collection<T> c, T val, Telemeter<T> tm) 
   {
      if (c == null || c.isEmpty())
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      } 

      int ix = 0;

      double distance = tm.distance(c.get(0), val);

      for (int i = 1; i < c.size(); i++) 
      {
         if (cdistance <= distance) 
         {
            ix = i;
            distance = cdistance;
         }
      }

      int theNum = c.get(ix);
      return theNum;
   }
}
```

Telemeter

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public interface Telemeter<E> extends Comparator<E> {

   double distance(E e1, E e2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `get(int)` method in [java.util.Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), hence your error. If you need the ability to pull out an arbitrary object, you should probably use `java.util.List`. Otherwise you could use the fact that `Collection` implements `Iterable` and use an enhanced for loop to perform the task.

Comment: I am pretty new to programming and everything I have tried seems to still have errors. Are there any other hints or something to possibly get me started?